# Error al hacer migraciones Laravel por cmd windows

Tags: laravel

[image: Hola, Tengo este error tratando de hacer migraciones]

Hola, Tengo este error tratando de hacer migraciones en laravel, alguna sugerencia

Comment: Tal vez llevas varias veces tratando de cargar una tabla que ya exista, intenta con `php artisan migrate:refresh` y si no te funciona, borra la tabla manualmente

Comment: Exactamente como dice @Cig. debes de  borrarla manualmente esa tabla. Después probar con nuevo migrate:refresh  en dado caso de que tengas relaciones con otras tablas y unas las creaste antes de. tendrás erorres. pero si no todo saldrá  bien .